Issue with loading edited image data in FilePond image editor using Cropper.js
I'm encountering an issue with my FilePond image editor, integrated with Cropper.js, where edited images are not being loaded properly when I attempt to edit them again. Instead of opening the edited version, the editor is loading the original image data. I've checked the editing instructions and the image data storage, but I'm unable to identify the root cause of the problem. How can I ensure that the edited image data, processed through Cropper.js, is correctly loaded when reopening the image editor for subsequent edits?
const editor = {
    // Called by FilePond to edit the image
    // - should open your image editor
    // - receives file object and image edit instructions
    open: (file, instructions) => {
        // open editor here

        // console.log("open editor")
        // console.log("file", file)
        // console.log("instructions", instructions)

        editImageModal.show();
        elem.find(".x-image").attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(file));
        const image = document.getElementById('image');
        
        const cropper = new Cropper(image, {
            aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
            crop(event) {
            },
        })

        // events
        elem.find(".x-btn-done").off("click").on("click", function() {
            const canvasData = cropper.getCanvasData();
            const cropData = cropper.getData();
            
            console.log("canvasData", canvasData)
            console.log("cropData", cropData)

            /* Ratio of selected crop area. */
            const cropAreaRatio = cropData.height / cropData.width

            /* Center point of crop area in percent. */
            const percentX = (cropData.x + cropData.width / 2) / canvasData.naturalWidth
            const percentY = (cropData.y + cropData.height / 2) / canvasData.naturalHeight

            /* Calculate available space round image center position. */
            const cx = percentX > 0.5 ? 1 - percentX : percentX
            const cy = percentY > 0.5 ? 1 - percentY : percentY


            /* Calculate image rectangle respecting space round image from crop area. */
            let width = canvasData.naturalWidth
            let height = width * cropAreaRatio
            if (height > canvasData.naturalHeight) {
                height = canvasData.naturalHeight
                width = height / cropAreaRatio
            }
            const rectWidth = cx * 2 * width
            const rectHeight = cy * 2 * height

            /* Calculate zoom. */
            const zoom = Math.max(rectWidth / cropData.width, rectHeight / cropData.height)

            var output = { // Data output object returned to FilePond from the editor in onconfirm
                data: {
                    crop: {
                    center: {
                        x: percentX,
                        y: percentY
                    },
                    flip: {
                        horizontal: cropData.scaleX < 0,
                        vertical: cropData.scaleY < 0
                    },
                    zoom: zoom,
                    rotation: cropData.rotate,
                    aspectRatio: cropAreaRatio
                    }
                }
            }
            
            setTimeout(() => {
                cropper.destroy();
            }, 500);
            editor.onconfirm(output);
            editImageModal.hide();
        });
        elem.find(".x-btn-reset").off("click").on("click", function() {
            cropper.reset();
        });
        elem.find(".x-btn-startcrop").off("click").on("click", function() {
            cropper.crop();
        });
        elem.find(".x-btn-move").off("click").on("click", function() {
            cropper.setDragMode('move');
        });
        elem.find(".x-btn-zoomin").off("click").on("click", function() {
            cropper.zoom(0.1);
        });
        elem.find(".x-btn-zoomout").off("click").on("click", function() {
            cropper.zoom(-0.1);
        });
        elem.find(".x-btn-rotateleft").off("click").on("click", function() {
            cropper.rotate(-90);
        });
        elem.find(".x-btn-rotateright").off("click").on("click", function() {
            cropper.rotate(90);
        });
        elem.find(".x-btn-flip-h").off("click").on("click", function() {
            cropper.scaleX(-cropper.getData().scaleX || -1);
        });
        elem.find(".x-btn-flip-v").off("click").on("click", function() {
            cropper.scaleY(-cropper.getData().scaleY || -1);
        });
        elem.find(".x-btn-reset").off("click").on("click", function() {
            cropper.reset();
        });
        $(editImageModal).find(".x-close-btn").off("click").on("click", function() {
            cropper.destroy();
            editor.onclose();
            editImageModal.hide();
        });
    },

    // Callback set by FilePond
    // - should be called by the editor when user confirms editing
    // - should receive output object, resulting edit information
    onconfirm: (output) => {
        // console.log(output)
    },

    // Callback set by FilePond
    // - should be called by the editor when user cancels editing
    oncancel: () => {},

    // Callback set by FilePond
    // - should be called by the editor when user closes the editor
    onclose: () => {},
};

$.fn.filepond.registerPlugin(
    FilePondPluginImagePreview, // Shows a preview of image files
    FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation, // Corrects orientation of pictures taken on mobile phones
    FilePondPluginFileValidateSize, // Limit the size of files being added
    FilePondPluginImageEdit, // Allows client-side image editing libraries like Pintura Image Editor to integrate with FilePond
    FilePondPluginFileEncode, // Encodes files as base64 data for submitting along a classic form post
    FilePondPluginImageTransform // Apply image transforms on the client before uploading.
);

$.fn.filepond.setDefaults({ // Change default settings of plugins
    maxFileSize: '10MB',
});

elem.find('.x-filepond').filepond({ // Turn input element into a pond with configuration options
    allowMultiple: true,
    credits: false,
    imageEditEditor: editor,
});         

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
